# Looking for a design pattern to process or batch process

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have the following structure. Until this point each element could be processed one by one.

```
interface ProcessingStrategyInterface
{
    public function process(Element $object): string;
}

class SomeListener
{
    /**
     * @var array<string, ProcessingStrategyInterface>
     */
    protected array $processers;

    public function __invoke(DocumentContent $event)
    {
        /**
         * @var array<string, list<Element>> $elements
         */
        $elementGroups = $event->getDynamicElements();

        foreach ($elementGroups as $type => $elements) {
            $processer = $this->processers[$type];

            foreach ($elements as $element) {
                $result = $processer->process($element);
            }
        }

        // [...]
    }
}
```

Now I have to add a new type of processer which takes the whole `list<Element>`, and processes them as one, then gives back a `string` result. For this a new interface could be defined.

```
interface BatchProcessingStrategyInterface
{
    /**
     * @param list<Element> $elements
     */
    public function batchProcess(array $elements): string;
}
```

This solution I feel a little bit off:

```
class SomeListener
{
    /**
     * @var array<string, ProcessingStrategyInterface|BatchProcessingStrategyInterface>
     */
    protected array $processers;

    public function __invoke(DocumentContent $event)
    {
        /**
         * @var array<string, list<Element>> $elements
         */
        $elementGroups = $event->getDynamicElements();

        foreach ($elementGroups as $type => $elements) {
            $processer = $this->processers[$type];

            if ($processer instanceof BatchProcessingStrategyInterface) {
                $result = $processer->batchProcess($elements);
            } else {
                foreach ($elements as $element) {
                    $result = $processer->process($element);
                }
            }
        }

        // [...]
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to solve this in a 100% type-strict way? What I want to achieve is to have single types everywhere by calling them the following way:

```
class SomeListener
{
    /**
     * @var array<string, ProcessingStrategyInterface>
     */
    protected array $processers;

    public function __invoke(DocumentContent $event)
    {
        /**
         * @var array<string, list<Element>> $elements
         */
        $elementGroups = $event->getDynamicElements();

        foreach ($elementGroups as $type => $elements) {
            $processer = $this->processers[$type];

            $result = $processer->process($elements);
        }

        // [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I right you want parallel process  `$elements`?

Comment: it's weird to call an interface `Abstract`.
To my mind you should call your method process the same way `process`

Comment: @AlexandrePainchaud yes right, I renamed the interface. I created the example in the hurry.

Comment: @ZoltánFekete I'm not sure about your needs, your both strategies do the same... does Urmat's comment Right ?

Comment: @AlexandrePainchaud Yes both strategy does the same BUT the `ProcessingStrategyInterface::process` accepts an instance of `Element`. However the `BatchProcessingStrategyInterface::batchProcess` accepts an array of `Element` (Because it has ti process them as a whole). I edited the question with what I try to achieve. I'm not sure that I understand Urmat's question: I don't know what does he mean by `parallel` in this context but I guess the answer is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came up with a solution with which I can keep to code type-hinted. Basically I just moved the logic a level up into the processor.

```
interface ProcessingStrategyInterface
{
    /**
     * @param list<Element> $elements
     */
    public function process(array $elements): string;
}

class ProcesserA implements ProcessingStrategyInterface
{
    public function process(array $elements): string
    {
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
             $this->processElement($element);
        }
    }
    
    protected function processElement(Element $element): string
    {
        // logic
    }
}

class BatchProcesserA implements ProcessingStrategyInterface
{
    public function process(array $elements): string
    {
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
             $this->processElement($element);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but if I were you, I would make smth like this:

```
interface ProcessingStrategyInterface {
    /**
     * @param Element $elements
     */
    public function process( Element $elements ): string;
}

interface BatchProcessingStrategyInterface
{
    /**
     * @param list<Element> $elements
     */
    public function process(array $elements): string;
}

class ProcesserA implements ProcessingStrategyInterface {
    public function process( Element $element ): string {
        // logic
    }
}

class BatchProcesserA implements BatchProcessingStrategyInterface {
    private ProcessingStrategyInterface $strategy;

    public function process( array $elements ): string {
        foreach ( $elements as $element ) {
            $this->strategy->processElement( $element );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the point would be to have an array of one certain interfaces implementation, then just loops through it and call just one method with the `list<Element>` parameter. With this solution the type of the array would be: `list<ProcessingStrategyInterface|BatchProcessingStrategyInterface>`. But i just figured out.